# Function not completing updating variables in the Script Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm newish to unity and I have come into a problem which I have no idea how to fix or even what is going wrong. My public void function is getting variables in from another script and updating them but when it is called in the update function, those variables are not updating and are instead logging 0.

```cs
public void statsImport(float XPImport)
    {
        float XPlevel = XPImport; 
        Debug.Log(XPlevel); 
    }
void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(XPlevel);
    }
```

When `Debug.Log` is called [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp3Zh.png) showing that it is not updating the variable.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You need to set the value to your class level variable, not a new local variable.  `XPlevel = XPImport`.  Adding `float` before that line is creating a local variable called `XPlevel` which is assigned the value and immediately discarded when the scope ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you spend some time reading about [variable scoping](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/variable-scope) in C#. You can think of these as blocks enclosed by `{ }`.

When you declare a variable inside of a scope (such as with `float XPlevel = XPImport`), that variable only exists *inside* of that scope:

```cs
public void statsImport(float XPImport)
{
    // start new method scope

    // declare variable `XPlevel` inside of that scope
    float XPlevel = XPImport; 
}

void Update()
{
    // start new method scope

    // `XPlevel` doesn't exist here
    Debug.Log(XPlevel);
}
```

Instead, what you probably want is something like this, where you make `XPlevel` a *field* inside of the *class-scope*:

```cs
public class MyComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    // declare class-level field
    private float XPlevel;

    public void statsImport(float XPImport)
    {
        // `XPlevel` exists here
        XPlevel = XPImport; 
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // `XPlevel` exists here
        Debug.Log(XPlevel);
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to edit the value of `XPlevel` inside of the Editor, add the `[SerializeField]` tag. This has the same effect as making `XPlevel` public, but only allowing the field to be set inside of your script:

```cs
[SerializeField]
private float XPlevel;
```

Once you're comfortable with that, you could also make `XPlevel` a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#auto-implemented-properties) instead:

```cs
[field: SerializeField]
public float XPlevel { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it, I was just being a little bit oblivious to C# as a language and trying to exclusively find the problem in Unity. I will definitely read more into variable scoping and C# as a whole, Thanks.